# Internationalization of static JS in Django

Tags: django, static, internationalization, django-templates

I want to translate a part of the JS in Django.

I've try the command `python manage.py makemessages -d djangojs` but it take only file in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in the `settings.py`

I've try to set a JS in a template directory, and it work perfectly.

I've the djangojs.po and i can generate the .mo when i compile.

**So the question is : How make message in static file?**

I've found the same problem 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095934/django-makemessages-not-working-for-js-files)
and
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625102/django-javascript-translation-not-working) but no one answer who keep a good architecture.

Please, save me!

**My architecture:**

- myapp

  - locale
  - static

    - myapp

      - js

        - try.js
  - template

    - myapp

      - try.html
  - views.py
  - urls.py
  - [...]

PS: Sorry for my english, i'm not native ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My error is when i set the STATIC_ROOT in settings.py.  In fact this variable say at Django where stock Static when it do a CollectStatic on the server, i used her for say where found my static (Django can find all static whitout informations, it find static on a folder static on the project folder or on the app folder)

Finally  :

**set this in the urls.py of the pro**

```
js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('app.kanboard',),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    [...]

    #Internationalization Javascript
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),

)
```

**In the template**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog' %}"></script>
```

**In the JS in static/my_app/my_file.js**

```
document.write(gettext('Ma chaine de caractère a traduire'))
```

**After, we rule this command-line**

```
python manage.py makemessages -d djangojs
```

Here, ***djangojs*** is the domain set in urls.py at the begin (It's a pseudo-convention)

At this time, we have a ***djangojs.po*** in the folder locale what we can compile as a standard ***.po***.

Link of the doc : [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code)

Lik of my ticket where you can find a sample project and explication in english : [The ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25162)

Good luck !

Comment: For future searchers: folow the ticket above. There explained explicitly